# having problems selecting svg child elements using d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have an svg that I'm trying to access and modify using `d3.js`.  The svg file name is `us-map.svg`.  I've included a reference to the svg in my html like this:

```
<object id="imgMap" data="us-map.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
</object>
```

I can select `imgMap` in my chrome watch panel like this:

```
var imgMap = d3.select('#imgMap')
```

However, I'm not able to select child elements.  For example, my `imgMap` svg has several child `<g>` elements but the child elements are not returned with this function:

```
d3.select('#imgMap').selectAll('g')
```

Am I missing something here?  I was thinking that d3 could be used to traverse and manipulate an existing svg?

Answer (score 3):

> I was thinking that d3 could be used to traverse and manipulate an existing SVG

This is pretty much what d3 does best. But when you write:

```
d3.select('#imgMap')
```

You are not selecting the SVG (unless you have an SVG with `id = "imgMap"`, which is not your case). You're using an `<object>`. Thus, you have to write:

```
var mySVG = d3.select(document.getElementById("imgMap").contentDocument);
```

And then select your groups using `mySVG`.

```
var myGroups = mySVG.selectAll("g");
```

Have in mind that this selection only works *after* the object has been loaded.

Source: https://benfrain.com/selecting-svg-inside-tags-with-javascript/

**EDIT**:

As requested by the OP, this is a basic working demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/RJOznJROiqTpo5dm9M7L?p=preview

In this plunkr, "mysvg.svg" is an external file (in your code, you'll have to provide the correct path). The code finds the SVG:

```
var mySVG = d3.select(document.getElementById("imgMap").contentDocument);
```

And then selects the blue circle inside the SVG, moving it to the right:

```
var myCircle = mySVG.select("#blueCircle"); 
myCircle.transition().duration(2000).attr("cx", 180);
```

Pay attention to this: I set a `setTimeout` of 1000ms, just to make sure that the object is loaded before the code runs.

Comment: this doesn't work for me.  contentDocument appears to return a reference to the parent html but I don't see any type of interface into the svg markup

Comment: can you post a basic jsbin or similar online demo with the most basic implementation for this?

Comment: figured it out.  I needed to access the svg node a little more specifically:

var mySvg = d3.select(document.getElementById("imgMap").contentDocument.childNodes[1]);

I'm sure this is due to some special formatting/nesting within my particular svg