# how to use jquery with d3 on same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

Using only d3 I'm able to use the following js which will set the idAttr var value to 'myId':

```
var idAttr = d3.select(document.getElementById('imgMap').contentDocument).select('#myId').attr('id');
```

However, if I add a jquery src to the page and include the line above within a document.ready() handler then jQuery throws the following exception:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null
    at zi.K_ [as attr] (https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js:6:24649)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/svg-tester-2.html:18:100)
    at j (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js:2:29588)
    at k (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js:2:29902) undefined
```

I'm guessing that jQuery tries to override d3's implementation of the attr() function.  I need to put my logic in the document.ready() function.  I'm sure that others have encountered this behavior/challenge.  What's a good solution for using d3 with jquery on the same page?

Comment: Can you use the unminified D3 version (https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js) instead and show what line the error occurs on?

Comment: I think the problem is a conflict between d3 and jQuery over the attr() function.  d3 has its own attr() function that it tries to use in a particular way.  however, jQuery has its own attr() function which is overriding the d3 implementation which is causing the error.  do I need to use a jQuery noconflict() implementation?  https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: This expression `document.getElementById('imgMap').contentDocument` is evaluated by the browser and then passed to d3. The error has nothing to do with d3, `document` is just `null` at that point.

Comment: Are you using IFrames? Is there any reason you can't just do: d3.select('#myId').attr(...)

Comment: I don't understand why there would be a `jQuery.Deferred exception`. Based on your code I wouldn't expect any deferred objects to be involved. `d3.select(...).select('#myId')` should select a D3 object, rather than a jQuery object, so the `attr` function will be D3's.

Comment: this line works without error:

var myId = d3.select(document.getElementById('imgMap').contentDocument).select('#myId');

this is needed to get a d3 handle to the element in the embedded svg object on the page.  However, there seems to be a conflict with the attr() function (since jQuery has that too).  This is where the error occurs:

var attrId = myId.attr('id');

Comment: There is no conflict, because `attr` in that line is a D3 method, not a jQuery one (even if they have the same name). The most probable cause for your problem is that your object is not loaded at the time of execution, as I told you before here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39649975/having-problems-selecting-svg-child-elements-using-d3

Comment: @gerardo, to provide some context, the line of code encounters the error when executed from within the following code structure:

$(function(){
//code here
});

However, the code works without error when invoked outside of a jquery context within the following code structure:

setTimeout(function(){
//code here
},1000);

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit late as I see this question was posted almost 5 years ago. But reading thru the answers I feel the original question/situation was not fully answered.

I have a situation like @user6867266 (original poster) where I am using jQuery and D3 side by side. I saw a post advising how to wrap a HTML element in a JavaScript variable in D3. The answer was *d3.select(**var holding html element**)*.

However when you do this it looks like the _parent member variable is set to NULL - I verified in the browser debug mode. Now if you call .attr() member function you get the error as mentioned in the post.

Now instead you simply get a pure D3 Selector object by passing a css selector string you will see that the _parent member field is NOT NULL and the .attr() member function works as expected.